# Fullcalendar - bad performance and continuous box destroy/create

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using fullcalendar and I really like it!
I am developing a simple application which needs to show a calendar able to rendere lots of events every day/week but I am facing an issue, since the pure web HTML/JS application runs in an embedded device with a chromium-based browser when I inject the events (let's say 1000 in a week in the week view) it tooks a lot of time, doesn't matter if I do it by .addEvent or .addEventSource, I also tried to put them inside a .batchrendering callback but no luck..
Then I tried to load them using the **"events (as a function)"** way but still it is slow.

The events data is retrieved by my AJAX callbacks in a centralized way thus I cannot use **"events (as a JSON feed)"** method.

The strange thing that I noticed is that the **successCallback** or the **.addEventSource** call returns after some reasonable time but then, the system, remains blocked for a lot of time, if I try to inspect the HTML I can see that the generated elements are destroyed and created again for a lot of time keeping my cpu at 100%

Is it a known issue or am I doing something very wrong?
Which should be the fastest way to insert the elements?

Note: I am using the fullcalendar v4, could be v5 a more powerful alternative?

Thanks :)

Comment: 1000 events per week is far too many. No human user can process or understand that quantity of data properly all at once, so there's no point in displaying it all at once. The calendar isn't designed to handle such volumes simultaneously. Rethink your user experience and consider if there is a sensible way you can provide some filtering of the events, or if you would be better to display it one day at a time, or something like that. Viewing that number of events at once will seem like chaos to your users.

Comment: Yes I know they are a lot of data! But even if trying with less events (let's say one every half-hour, around 330 for week) my view is uncontrollable, the vertical scroll doesn't work.. I tried to debug a little by deleting the HTML elements by hand from the developer tools but It doesn't change, It means that it Is not slowed down by the events amount in the HTML, also I see that the events spontaneously re-appear again so there Is probably some kind of loop always going on in the calendar because they are not fetched again from my source

Comment: Have you used the JavaScript debugger to try and find out where that loop is? If you need any more help from us you'll need to show us enough code to reproduce the issue

Comment: I am Just making some hypotesys on the encountered behavior